# Xpages - Dojo Value Picker [multiple choice, other db, search function]

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I need to build a dojo value picker that has the following capabilities:

1) Be able to choose views from a different DB
2) Be able to choose multiple values
3) Be able to have the user search for a value

I cannot figure out how to get all three.

A simple value picker appears to not support search. 
If I user a dominoViewValuePicker, I cannot have both dojo types:

extlib.dijit.PickerCheckbox

and

extlib dijit pickerlistsearch

## Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks to Paul and others for helping. I did get this to work by using the dominoViewValuePicker. See my example below, which I hope could help someone else.

```
    <xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker1"
        dialogTitle="Choose From This List" pickerIcon="/picker.png"
        for="Approvers" dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:dominoViewValuePicker viewName="(YOURVIEWNAME)">
                <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var serv:String = session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer();
serv + "!!" + "YOURDB.nsf";}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
            </xe:dominoViewValuePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>

</xe:valuePicker>
```

Comment: You can realize that with select2: http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/select2.xsp Have a look at the multi select example.

Comment: That is a very nice selection control, I am going to give it a try.

Comment: We use it a lot in our projects and it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have both dojo types. But with extlib.dijit.pickerlistsearch, double-clicking selects entries and does allow multiple to be selected. See http://www.intec.co.uk/extension-library-value-picker-and-extlib-dijit-pickerlistsearch/

Comment: Paul, thanks I missed that in your post. I did actually get this to work. I will post the code in the original questions so others might use it.